# How to create unique ID number for values in separate columns that are connected?

Tags: r

I have a strange data set that has claim numbers in one column and in another column has a "companion" number. The companion number values are either equal to a different claim number that occurred in the same event as the claim that corresponds to the companion number you are looking at, or blank meaning that the claim number is the companion number.

All claim numbers are unique in the entire data set.

The most this goes up to is 3 claims per one event. I need to create a unique identifier column that will group these claims as 1 unique event. There are a majority of 1 claim 1 event cases, but a significant number of 2 cases per event and some 3 cases per event.

2 cases per event Example:

```
claim_num    companion_num
A            B
B            A
```

Or

```
claim_num    companion_num
A            B
B            B
```

3 cases per event Example:

```
claim_num    companion_num
A            B
B            
C            A
```

The 3 case per event scenario is particularly tricky because there are many possible combinations that can occur. In this example, claim number B is the 'original' because all paths can be traced back to claim B.

I need something that looks like these and will work for 2 case and 3 case events:

```
claim_num    companion_num    ID
A            B                1
B                             1
C            A                1
```

Or

```
claim_num    companion_num    ID
A            B                1
B            B                1
```

Ive tried many times in excel but I cant figure out how to do this. I know some R so I am hoping for some guidance here. Ive gotten to the point where I can fill in any blank companion numbers with its claim number, but that is it.

Comment: we need more information.  How is one to know that ID 1 applies to A-B, A-blank, C-A?  Is every claim_num and companion_num  A, B or C, or do they get bigger?  Are A, B and C people's names, IDs, or what?  Can you give a longer example of how you want things to look, with several different IDs?